# Variables disappear on url rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm completely stuck with .htaccess trying to rewrite requests so :

```
website.com/SOMEPAGE

website.com/SOMEPAGE/?arg1=a&arg2=b&arg3
```

...becomes...

```
website.com/index.php?page=SOMEPAGE

website.com/index.php?page=SOMEPAGE&arg1=a&arg2=b&arg3
```

My .htaccess looks like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)\/?(\?(.+))?$ index.php?page=$1&$3 [NC,L]
```

And then in index.php :

```
<script>
  var vars = '<?php print(json_encode($_GET)); ?>';
  console.log(vars);
</script>
```

The console only ever logs :

> {"page":"SOMEPAGE"}

arg1, arg2 etc. have disappeared.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never receive the query string in your `RewriteRule` directive. To forward the previous query params after a rewrite, you use [the **`QSA`** flag](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/rewrite/flags#flag_qsa):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

and that will take care of forwarding your request parameters.